# Bluetooth Issue

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10

A few days ago I bought a new notebook (hp 250 g7). The network card (Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac (1x1) Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.2 Combo, non-vPro) uses proprietary drivers. Wifi is working with no problems, but bluetooth doesn´t work at all.

Edit:

output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of dmesg | grep -i blue:

no output

output of usb-devices:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.03
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.3.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04d9 ProdID=1702 Rev=04.06
S:  Manufacturer= 
S:  Product=USB Keyboard
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=093a ProdID=2510 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=PixArt
S:  Product=USB Optical Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.03
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.3.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Edit 2:

output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db1 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems BG3 NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

Edit 3:

output of dmesg | grep hci:

```
[    0.989892] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.989895] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.989909] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.989926] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.989928] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.989940] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.989950] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.990309] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.990316] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.991411] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
[    0.991416] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.991645] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.993642] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.993646] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.993650] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.993700] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.241302] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    1.252583] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl RAID mode
[    1.252586] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    1.252929] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.253712] scsi host1: ahci
[ 8625.749884] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 8626.965541] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue; usb-devices` terminal command.

Comment: What about `lspci`?

Comment: You don't have a BT device. It should be seen in `lsusb` as `0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. `

Comment: Linux 5.2 includes a new mainline(open-source) driver for your wifi chipset known as `rtw88`. It supports rtl8812be and rtl8812ce chipsets. However, the news didn't mention bluetooth(https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Realtek-RTW88-WiFi-Linux-Driver). Could you post the output of `dmesg | grep hci`? (`hci0` is the default name for a bluetooth adapter)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1742613/comments/1 for the link to download the bluetooth driver for your 8821cd.